# Android notification at exact time

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, alarm

For the life of me, I can't figure out why I can't set an exact time for an android notification. Been trying to figure this out for a few days, and still don't understand why.

Sometimes, it works on the exact same time from the time picker. But, sometimes it's 20 seconds, 34 seconds or even a full minute late. If someone could help me out, It'd be much appreciated because I don't know what else to do. I'm setting the time to the alarm manager from date milliseconds.

Broadcast Receiver:

```
public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    int code = intent.getIntExtra("code", 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle("Task reminder!")
            .setTicker(intent.getStringExtra("taskText"))
            .setContentText(intent.getStringExtra("taskText"))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
            .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, code, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .build();
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    notificationManager.notify(code, notification);
}
```

}

MainActivity:

```
int code = new Random().nextInt(1200) + 

                    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlertReceiver.class);
                    intent.putExtra("taskText", taskInput.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("code", code);
                    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), code, intent, 0);

                    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, reminder, alarmIntent);

                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
```

Getting my time from this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, datePicker.getYear());
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, datePicker.getMonth());
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getCurrentHour());
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

Comment: Please consult the docs for [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). The `set()` method hasn't been exact since KitKat.

Comment: Hi mike. I'm now looking at the setExact method. It's now giving me an error: Call requires API level 19 (current min is 15): android.app.AlarmManager#setExact

Comment: You would need to check the current Android version, and call the appropriate method for each. There's an example of that in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40931966), following the `//MARSHMALLOW OR ABOVE` comment in the first code block.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it! Replaced set() with setExact().

Thanks, Mike!